# Wifi speed is lower after dual boot

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, wireless, windows-10

Before dual boot i was only using Windows 10 in which the speed was just the one i paid for -40 Mbps. After dual booting Ubuntu 16.04 the WiFi speed in both Windows and on Ubuntu have been affected. It became less than half of what i was supposed to get.I get a maximum speed of like 17-18 Mbps on both the OSs. But while on Ethernet i get a proper speed...How can i make it proper. Yes i have tried methods from other pages but they seem to have no effect on the computer!!!
Please Help!!!

Comment: You are mistaken. Dual booting does not and cannot interfere with one or other OS' devices/drivers. And WiFi is expected to be slower than Ethernet, always! (You probably measured with Ethernet before).

Comment: No Michael. Last time too i had measured it with wifi only. Even on my mobile i get 40mbps. Its some problem with the OS

Comment: So it's the same problem with both OSes at the same time... What does it tell you?

Comment: i dont know...What is it

Comment: It tells you that either a) you're mistaken (most likely) or b) something happened with the hardware because, again, a standalone OS or multiboot makes absolutely no difference in the way each OS handles drivers and hardware therefore whatever happens with Windows now cannot be blamed on the dualboot the same way whatever happens with Ubuntu now can't be blamed on Windows.

Comment: Welll, I find it hard to believe that its a hardware problem since even JUST BEFORE dual booting, I had checked to wifi speed and it was perfect. And RIGHT  AFTER  I booted into Ubuntu, it worsened...

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/217463/wi-fi-vs.-ethernet-how-much-better-is-a-wired-connection/ Quoting: *Ethernet is just plain faster than Wi-Fi—there’s no getting around that fact.*